# Google play In App Billing Services for multiple products

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I developed an application using the inapp billing services.

```
helper.launchPurchaseFlow(MainActivity.this,ITEM_SKU,10001,purchasedFinishedListener,"my_purchase_token");
```

this is implemented using a [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpnNEGOF3ck&list=PLvPqrYVmSBHeCbUccEYkkaqggtYkoJrXX). This shows how to implement one product. Let Say i have several products to offer for the users to buy.

in,

launchPurchaseFlow(Activity,ITEM_SKU,REQUESTCODE,PurchasedFinishedListener,DeveloperPayload)

my question is if i offer 5 options to buy do i need to create 5 request codes??

```
private static final REQUESTCODE1=10001;
private static final REQUESTCODE2=10002;
private static final REQUESTCODE3=10003;
private static final REQUESTCODE4=10004;
private static final REQUESTCODE5=10005;
```

like that?? or can i get away with just one REQUESTCODE?

Answer (score 0):

One productID is equal to one purchasable product item. As you can read in the [Administering In-app Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html?visit_id=1-636561120356435912-495735887&hl=en&rd=1), you cannot reuse a productID. So you creating different productIDs is correct. You can learn more of in-app billing in that link.